# How to draw from the database a number that is from a random number to a number in the database?

Tags: php, sql

I want to pick a number from 1 to X which in X shows something from the database.

The code before you, I wrote it and I think it's supposed to make the most of it, but it doesn't work

```
$random = rand(1,3);
    $up_pras = $db->query("UPDATE `events` SET up_pras=up_pras + '".$random."' WHERE ID='".$user_id."'");
    $diamonds = $up_pras;
    $msg = '<div class="green" style="width:400px;">yes! i give you: '.$diamonds.' diamonds!</div> ';
    mysql_query("UPDATE `resources` SET `geluksrad` = `geluksrad` - '1', `diamonds` = `diamonds`+ '".$diamonds."' WHERE ID='".$user_id."'");
```

Here's another code I tried but a complete failure

```
$random = rand(1,3);
$up_pras = $db->query("UPDATE `events` SET up_pras=up_pras + '".$random."' WHERE ID='".$user_id."'");
$diamonds = rand(1,$up_pras);
$msg = '<div class="green" style="width:400px;">yes! i give you: '.$diamonds.' diamonds!</div> ';
mysql_query("UPDATE `resources` SET `geluksrad` = `geluksrad` - '1', `diamonds` = `diamonds`+ '".$diamonds."' WHERE ID='".$user_id."'");
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  What does this mean?  "I want to pick a number from 1 to X which in X shows something from the database."  Also tag with the database you are using.  And, learn to use parameters rather than munging query strings.

Comment: Ok, for example, the number I want is between 1 and 5, the number 5 is called X, now, every time someone clicks an example of "let me" catch up on the database and whoever sends on "give me" will get no 5, but 6 and so on

Comment: You appear to be using 2 different mysql apis; you can't do that. Plus, if you want to "pick" random stuff, you need SELECT, not UPDATE.

Answer (score -2):

in the end it was decided to use another style, the code that works is:

```
$random = rand(1,1);
$diamonds = rand(1,$ud['rsc']['diamonds_up_spin'])/5;
$msg = '<div class="green" style="width:400px;">yes! i give you: '.$diamonds.' diamonds!</div> ';
mysql_query("UPDATE `resources` SET `geluksrad` = `geluksrad` - '1', `diamonds` = `diamonds`+ '".$diamonds."', `diamonds_up_spin` = `diamonds_up_spin`+ '".$random."' WHERE ID='".$user_id."'");
```

Thanks so much to everyone who tried to help

Comment: If you really still use `mysql_*` functions you should update your PHP version! `mysql_*` functions are deprecated as of PHP 5.5 and has been removed as of PHP 7!

Besides this your SQL is vulnarable for SQL injections!